# Simulating multiple routers on the same machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, network-programming

I want to implement Distance Vector Routing in Python and for this purpose i want to simulate multiple routers on the same machine who will have the ability to send and receive packets, how do i achieve this? To clarify my  question, i'm not asking for the implementation details but rather how to execute multiple copies of the same python script with different configuration details (Neighbors, Costs of Associated links etc) simultaneously. **(Python Version:3.5)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've achieved my desired functionality by creating a generic script and passing it different configuration values by creating a Batch file (.bat) which has the configuration values being passed to the python script (which are later on saved in different variables and used as desired e.g: the router's name or the port number being used to send packets etc). The name of the script and environment (python) is the only constant thing, the parameters may depend on your implementation:

```
python [fileName].py [parameters]
```